# Gedit error: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time' is not installed

Tags: gnome, gedit, plugins

When running Gedit from Terminal, I encounter an error stating that `Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time' is not installed`. Neither purging and installing using `apt-get` nor removing and installing using the Ubuntu Software Center helped.

How can I bring back my Gedit? Where can I find the time-plugin?

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins`

Comment: Didn't help, @NewUSer.

Comment: The schema is provided by the `gedit-common` package rather than `gedit-plugins` I think (at least in 14.04)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gedit-common` also doesn't work, @steeldriver.

Comment: If you've manually deleted the file somehow, you would need to *reinstall* the package: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit-common`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start by identifying exactly what file is causing the issue - something like

```
$ find /usr/share -iname '*schema*' | grep gedit
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.pythonconsole.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.externaltools.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.gschema.xml
```

The first result appears to be the file we are looking for. Now we can check which package provides that file

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time.gschema.xml
gedit-common: /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time.gschema.xml
```

So it looks like `gedit-common` is the relevant package - assuming that the schema file got manually deleted somehow, you should be able to restore it by re-installing the package, either from your GUI package manager of choice or from the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit-common
```

Comment: @MERose the first result is `org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time.gschema.xml`, which appears to be the schema corresponding to the error message in your question - sorry if that was not obvious

Comment: Just improving the answer for future readers ;)